# Проверка boolean массива на true

Tags: java, массивы

У меня есть `boolean` массив, в котором хранятся значения CheckBox-ов (`true` или `false`). В случае, если все элементы массива будут `true`, мне нужно выполнять некоторую операцию. Так вот, как проверить массив на `true` во всех элементах? Проверять нужно на наличие всех `true`. Пробовал так:

```
boolean[] checked = { true, true, false, true };
for (int z = 0; z < checked.length; z++) {
    if (checked[z] == false)
        System.out.println("в массиве есть false!");
}
```

Получается, что при каждой встрече `false` в массиве, программа покажет сообщение. Но мне нужно обратное - показ сообщения при отсутствии `false`. Добавляю `else`:

```
    else
        System.out.println("в массиве только true!");
```

Таким образом я добьюсь повторения сообщения столько раз, сколько значений `true` в массиве. **Мне нужно выполнить операцию только один раз, в случае, если в массиве только `true`!**

**UPD** Немного подумав, я написал вот такое:

```
int x = 1;
for (int z = 0; z < checked.length; z++) {
    x = x * ((checked[z] == true) ? 1 : 2);
}
if (x == 1) {
    //мои действия
}
```

Я с помощью тернарного оператора в каждой итерации умножаю единицу на саму себя (если `true`) или на двойку (если `false`). В итоге, если полученное число равно единице, значит, в массиве только `true`.

Comment: Циклом. Рвать на первом встреченном `false`, иначе `true`. Вы с языком вообще знакомы?

Comment: @D-side, пытаюсь, но ничего не получается.

Comment: Этот комментарий не добавляет информации. Приложите, что пробовали и где оно ломается.

Comment: @D-Side, у меня необычная ситуация. Нужно что-то делать не при наличии хотя бы одного false, а при наличии всех true. Если я сделаю, так как вы сейчас думаете, через if: я получу возмлжность что-то делать при встрече false и при не встрече false. Ни то, ни другое мне не надо. Надо что-то делать только если везде true. А насчёт одного/всех false - ничего. На это нет никаких действий

Comment: Это весьма заурядная ситуация. Что думаю я, вы не поняли :) Добавьте то, что пробовали.

Comment: почему вместо массива не использовать какой-нибудь List и метод contains

Comment: @MrGarison, так нужно менять всю логику, так как больше половины кода в проекте уже отлично работает с обычным массивом

Comment: код который в UPD удалите скорее и никому не показывайет. Лучше даже не говорить что мысли такие были

Comment: @MrGarison, не показывать? (: Это подкол?

Comment: именно. Отметьте правильный ответ если он есть :)

Comment: @MrGarison, ваш, мсье XD но, UPD я оставлю) пусть люди поугарают

Comment: @СергейГрушин и так, между делом: не экономьте на пробелах и не используйте `== false` и `== true`. `x = x * (checked[z] ? 1 : 2);` и покороче, и смотрится чище.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Напишите метод

```
public boolean checkArray(boolean[] checked){
    for (boolean b : checked) {
        if (!b) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

и потом просто вызывайте

```
if (checkArray(checked)){
        //ваши действия
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean[] checked= {true, true, false, true};
boolean areAllElementsTrue = true;
for(int z = 0; z < checked.length; z++) {
    if (checked[z] == false) {
    areAllElementsTrue = false;
    break;
    }
}
if (areAllElementsTrue) {
    System.out.println("в массиве только true!");        
    // Выполняйте ваши действия
}
```

Comment: спасибо, но что-то не так. Операция выполняется произвольно, то в случае двух true из трёх, то ещё как-нибудь. Дело в том, что я "завожу" эту проверку при снятии/ставке чекбокса. Не знаю, может дело в этом. Я меняю значения массива вместе с состояниями чекбоксов.

Comment: @Сергей Грушин В моем ответе добавлены фигурные скобки для if. Теперь вроде работает. Попробуйте

Comment: @СергейГрушин Стало понятно, почему до этого не работало. Без этих скобок был выход из цикла после проверки первого элемента, и если он был true, то наш флаг так и оставался true.

Comment: спасибо, но я уже нашёл выход) добавил в вопрос